# Determine whether a MFT is GPU or CPU?

Tags: winapi, video-encoding, ms-media-foundation

I can get the name of an MFT with `MFT_FRIENDLY_NAME_Attribute` and check if it is hardware or software with `MFT_ENUM_FLAG_HARDWARE`, how can I check whether the encoder is CPU or GPU based?

i.e. Intel QuickSync is CPU, NVIDIA H.264 Encoder MFT is GPU, etc

The encoders are fetched via `MFTEnumEx(MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_ENCODER, ...);` which provides an array of `IMFActivate` and from there I can get MFT flags and the encoder's GUID.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Nvidia Encoder NVENC with Media Foundation for H264 on Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32394456/using-nvidia-encoder-nvenc-with-media-foundation-for-h264-on-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I check whether the encoder is CPU or GPU based

MFTs don't indicate whether they are CPU or GPU based. They don't have to and then it does not make a lot of sense either.

`MFT_ENUM_FLAG_HARDWARE` flag you already discovered is already telling you the information you want.

> [`MFT_ENUM_FLAG_HARDWARE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfapi/ne-mfapi-_mft_enum_flag)
>
> The MFT performs hardware-based data processing, using either the AVStream driver or a GPU-based proxy MFT. MFTs in this category always process data asynchronously.

This flag tells that there is no CPU implementation behind this encoder and it's some hardware which handles the encoding. What hardware exactly? Normally, it's GPU.

There is no AMD, Intel or NVIDIA Media Foundation encoder with `MFT_ENUM_FLAG_HARDWARE` and in the same time "CPU based" (If H.264/AVC or H.265/HEVC is in question, there is no CPU/software encoder in Media Foundation form factor from the mentioned vendors at all).

Comment: Thanks, based on the flag's comment - why am I getting Intel QuickSync H264 for hardware, when I have a Intel CPU and NVIDIA GPU?

Comment: Most of Intel CPUs have onboard GPU with encoder ASICs on it, you install video drivers and you have video encoder MFTs with them.

Comment: When I use the Intel QuickSync MFT my CPU usage is high and GPU isn't touched, so I'm sure it's using the CPU to do encoding. Also, I'm trying to make some sort of priority list, without hardcoding, is there a way to do this? Such as preferring NVIDIA over Intel.

Comment: I doubt you are correctly interpreting what you are seeing. Also in most cases it is not about just telling whether you want this or that MFT: perofrmance depends on more factors, esp. what is the encoder input exactly. Maybe code and details how you measure the load could help.

Comment: I believe it is due to Intel using the integrated GPU.